# On running .exe, I am getting a NotImplementedError

Tags: python-2.7, db2, windows-7-x64, cx-freeze

I have a python code, which connects to **IBM DB2**.
It works just fine when I run through the python interpreter.

Now, I have created a `.exe` file out of it using `cx_Freeze`

So when I run this `.exe` file, I get the below error:

```
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip
```

[image]

The above error is for `ibm_db` package.

In the `site-packages` folder, I have these two folders for `ibm_db`-

**ibm_db_dlls**

**ibm_db-2.0.6-py2.7.egg-info**

Setup file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'WIN32GUI'

include_files = ['dbc.ico', 'excel_funcs.py']
packages = ['ibm_db', 'openpyxl', 'Tkinter', 'os', 'packaging', 'ttk', 'functools', 'time', 'datetime', 'six', 'subprocess', 'tkMessageBox', 'logging']

setup(
    name="DB_Checker",
    version="1.0",
    author="PEJK",
    options= {'build_exe' : {'include_files' : include_files, 'packages' : packages, 'includes' : ['re']}},
    executables = [Executable('DB_Checker.py', base=base)]
)
```

Can anyone please suggest what could be the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I uninstalled `ibm_db 2.0.6` which is in `.egg-info` file package, and installed `ibm_db 2.0.5` which is in `.egg` file package. Created a `.exe` with `cx_Freeze`, and this .exe works fine. I am still exploring on how to sort this issue with `.egg-info` packages.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I found a very similar issue with python 3.9, cx_freeze 6.11.1 and ibm_db 3.1.3 on Windows 10.

First, I got the FileNotFoundError that I resolved by correcting the path to the IBM clientdrivers. Then I got the NotImplementedError because the ibm_db.py was not functioning from inside the zipped folder (library.zip).
The cause is that the transformation into executable (cx_freeze) breaks the expected directory structure for ibm_db to work and also by putting the ibm_db and ibm_dbi modules inside the zipped folder where the modules do not work properly.

This is how I eventually worked around the issues without modifying the source code of the two libraries

My setup.py looked like this

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os, sys
 
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
build_options = {
    'packages': ["ibm_db_dlls"],
    'includes': ["clidriver", "ibm_db", "ibm_db_dbi"],
    'replace_paths' : [("*", "")],
    }
 
base = 'Console'
 
executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base)
]
 
setup(name='script',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'Description...',
      options = {'build_exe': build_options},
      executables = executables)
```

Then I built the executable

```
python setup.py build
```

This is the structure of the lib folder after transforming the script into an executable:

```
build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib
|-- clidriver
|-- ibm_db_dlls
|-- library.zip
|   |-- ibm_db.pyc
|   |-- ibm_db_dbi.pyc
```

If I ran the script I would get FileNotFoundError. Thus, I moved the files ibm_db_dbi.pyc and ibm_db.pyc from the library.zip folder to the parent folder. See the file structure below:

```
build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib
|-- clidriver
|-- ibm_db_dlls
|-- ibm_db.pyc
|-- ibm_db_dbi.pyc
|-- library.zip
```

Now I am able to run the executable without errors.

I would like the solution to be more fine-tuned than this, e.g. handling this in the setup.py file, but did not find a such solution.